# Simple Ruby Programing, getting error and don't understand why,

Tags: ruby, tree

I'm very new in Ruby programing, I spent a lot of time on this program but I came to a point that I don't understand the error I'm getting,

It would be great if you can help in finding the error and possibly fix it.

Thank you.

---

[Here is the complete description of program and actual code:](http://amir734jj.rr.nu/dropbox)

Error:

```
C:/Users/Amir-i7/Dropbox/CS431/hwk9/hwk9.rb:148:in `+': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
    from C:/Users/Amir-i7/Dropbox/CS431/hwk9/hwk9.rb:148:in `test_tree'
    from C:/Users/Amir-i7/Dropbox/CS431/hwk9/hwk9.rb:152:in `<main>'
```

Code:

```
module TreeEnum
  def any? f 
  s = false
  self.iterate(f).each do |child|
  s = s || child.iterate(f) end
  s
  end 

  def inject(f,c)
  z = lambda {|data| f.call(data,c)}
  iterate z
  end
end

class Leaf

  def initialize s 
    @data = s
  end

  def concatAll
    @data
  end

  def firstAlphabetical 
    @data
  end

  def iterate(itr)
    itr.call(@data)
  end
end

class BinaryNode
  include TreeEnum

  def initialize (left, right)
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end

  def concatAll
    @left.concatAll + @right.concatAll
  end

  # not part of the homework
  def BinaryNode.firstAlphabetical (s1, s2)
    if s1.casecmp(s2) < 0 then s1 else s2 end
  end

  def firstAlphabetical 
    s1 = @left.firstAlphabetical
    s2 = @right.firstAlphabetical 
    if s1.casecmp(s2) < 0 then s1 else s2 end
  end

  def iterate itr
    @left.iterate itr
    @right.iterate itr  
  end


  def BinaryNode.concatAll tree
    s = "";
    tree.iterate(lambda { |data| s = s + data })
    s
  end

end


class NaryNode
  include TreeEnum
  def initialize childArray
    @childArray = childArray.clone
  end

  def iterate itr
    # use the "each" method of array to pass "itr" to the iterate method of each element in @childArray
    @childArray.each do |child|
      child.iterate itr
    end
  end


  def concatAll 
    # use the "inject" method of array to concatenate the strings of each node in @childArray
    s = ""
    @childArray.each do |child|
      s = s + child.concatAll
    end
    s
  end

  def firstAlphabetical
    # use the "inject" method of array to retrieve the smallest string of the nodes in @childArray
    @childArray.inject(@childArray[0]) {|first, node| if first.firstAlphabetical.casecmp(node.firstAlphabetical) < 0 then first.firstAlphabetical else node.firstAlphabetical end}
  end
end

class String
  def iterate itr
    itr.call(self)
  end
  def concatAll 
    self
  end
  def firstAlphabetical
    self
  end
end





def test_print t2
  puts "t2.concatAll: " + t2.concatAll.to_s
  puts 
  puts "t2.firstAlphabetical: " + t2.firstAlphabetical.to_s
  puts
  puts "t2.iterate(lambda { |s| puts s }):"  
  t2.iterate(lambda { |s| puts s })
end

def test_tree
  l0 = Leaf.new "What "
  l1 = Leaf.new "a "
  l2 = Leaf.new "great "
  l3 = Leaf.new "day"
  l4 = Leaf.new "!"
  t0 = BinaryNode.new(l0,l1)
  t1 = BinaryNode.new(t0,l2)
  t2 = NaryNode.new([t1,l3,l4])

  test_print t2

  puts "\nThe following works after question 2\n\n"

  t2 = NaryNode.new([t1, "day", "!"])

  test_print t2

  puts "\nThe following works after question 3\n\n"

  puts "any word starting with `great': " + t2.any?(lambda {|x| x.start_with?("great")}).to_s
  puts
  puts "capitalize: " + t2.inject((lambda {|acc, elm| acc + elm.capitalize + " "}), "") 
end


test_tree
```

I already tried replacing line 148 with

```
puts "capitalize: " + t2.inject((lambda {|acc, elm| acc + elm.capitalize + " "}), "").to_s
```

But I get:

```
capitalize: [#<BinaryNode:0x00000002ce5958 @left=#<BinaryNode:0x00000002ce5980 @left=#<Leaf:0x00000002ce5ae8 @data="What ">, @right=#<Leaf:0x00000002ce5a98 @data="a ">>, @right=#<Leaf:0x00000002ce5a48 @data="great ">>, "day", "!"]
```

Comment: It would be nice to know what's in line 148. Anyway, looks like you're trying to concatenate an array with a string...

Comment: It would be great if you can help and possible solutions, remember I can't change testing part.

Comment: These are two different problems, how would you like to solve the latter?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Please be more specific, I'm really new in Ruby, I spent a lot of time on this program, please help me to finish the program.

Comment: Yes, we're here to help you. That's why I asked what you would like to do? I can tell you're not getting an error anymore, and that the output of line 148 isn't what you'd like it to be. What would you like it to be?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Thank you, based on program description it should be "capitalize: What A Great Day !"

Comment: Looking at your code, it doesn't seem like you last line will work. Your NaryNode behaves differently (responds to different methods) than your Leaf and BinaryNode. In order to iterate over them with inject, they'd all have to respond to the same method that returns the data (the string you want to print out to say "What a great day!"). Try to figure out what structural problem you have and then post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on line 148:

```
puts "capitalize: " + t2.inject((lambda {|acc, elm| acc + elm.capitalize + " "}), "")
```

You're trying to concatenate an array with a string, and using `+` will throw an error unless you call `to_s` on the array like this:

```
puts "capitalize: " + t2.inject((lambda {|acc, elm| acc + elm.capitalize + " "}), "").to_s
```

Otherwise you can use Ruby's string interpolation (which call `to_s` on objects implicitly):

```
puts "capitalize: #{t2.inject((lambda {|acc, elm| acc + elm.capitalize + " "}), "")}"
```

This will solve your error, if you have any more questions I'll try to answer them in comments.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Didn't work, I get: capitalize: [#<BinaryNode:0x00000002ce5958 @left=#<BinaryNode:0x00000002ce5980 @left=#<Leaf:0x00000002ce5ae8 @data="What ">, @right=#<Leaf:0x00000002ce5a98 @data="a ">>, @right=#<Leaf:0x00000002ce5a48 @data="great ">>, "day", "!"]

Comment: I bet you don't get the error anymore though, right? This looks like it works, but just not the output you'd like. You have to work on that yourself ;)

Comment: I know you're in a hurry with your homework but it would be a good idea to get the basics before you mess around with things like lambda functions...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that diego.greyrobot answered the question regarding the particular error you were getting: you should be sure that the variable you're running a method on is of a class that your method can accept. I have an extra bit of advice to make it easier for you to find out what classes your variables are returning.

Sometimes it's difficult to know what class a variable will be. For example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
x << y    #=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
z = x[1] + x[3]
```

In the example above, you might think that x would become [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. However, since the << operator grabs whatever on it's left wholesale without regard for where it's putting it, you get [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]

If you throw in:

```
puts x[3].class    #=> Array
```

Ruby will tell you what class your variable is, alerting you to the problem in your code. This is a handy debugging technique that works well when you get those "conversion" errors.